# How to select the data from a table when it's ability is in an other table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:
-Sales
-Items_cstm
-Items

Sales and Items_cstm contains the data I have to get with the query and Items the ability of the item "Deleted (1 or 0)" (and dome more info I don't need).
The Items_cstm's id is = Items's id.

I have to list the Sales of the Items which aren't deleted (0).

I've tried somehow with inner join but it didn't work and I don't really know what am I doing wrong:

```
SELECT Items_cstm.quantity
FROM Items_cstm, Sales
WHERE '".$_POST['name']."' = Sales.name
AND
INNER JOIN Items ON Items_cstm.id = Items.id
WHERE Items.deleted = 0;
```

Comment: How are the `Sales` table and the `Items` or the `Items_cstm` tables connected? As far as I can see there's no foreign key used in this query for the table `Sales`.

Comment: Your join needs to be part of the from clause, not where.  If you post your table schema, we can be of more assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join your tables like this (but you did not show the link between `Items_cstm` and `sales` - you have to modify that)

```
SELECT ic.quantity
FROM Items_cstm ic
INNER JOIN Sales s on s.id = ic.id
INNER JOIN Items i ON ic.id = i.id
WHERE i.deleted = 0
AND s.name = '".$escapedName."'
```

Also **always** escape your user input.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out from this and finally it works! Of course I escaped the input!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT Items_cstm.quantity
FROM Items_cstm 
INNER JOIN Sales ON sales.JOINCOLUMN = Items_cstm.JOINCOLUMN  
INNER JOIN Items ON Items_cstm.id = Items.id
WHERE Sales.name = '".$_POST['name']."'
WHERE Items.deleted = 0;
```

Replace JOINCOLUMN above with the columns that let you match records  between  these two tables

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT Items_cstm.quantity
FROM Items_cstm
INNER JOIN Items ON Items_cstm.id = Items.id
INNER JOIN Sales ON Items_cstm.id = Sales.item_id // ??? check this one for column names
WHERE '$name' = Sales.name AND Items.deleted = 0;
```

Beware of SQL injection.